Ruby with Postgresql raising NumericValueOutOfRange
I'm trying to do the following query using ruby and pqsql, but when trying a range with more than 1.000 registers I'm receiving an error.
.
.
.
user.left_outer_joins(:coverage_radius).where(id: i).where(
'3959 * acos(
  cos(
    radians(?)
  )
  * cos(
    radians(coverage_radius.latitude)
  )
  * cos(
    radians(?) - radians(coverage_radius.longitude)
  )
  + sin(radians(?))
  * sin(radians(coverage_radius.latitude))
) <= coverage_radius.miles',
job.latitude,
job.longitude,
job.latitude
).count
.
.
.

The error I'm receiving is:
7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  input is out of range (ActiveRecord::RangeError)

/var/deploy/proxypics_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': ERROR:  input is out of range (PG::NumericValueOutOfRange)

I'm dealing with numeric and double numbers, basically doing some maths with latitude/longitude. should I convert everything to double or everything to numeric to solve this?

The error message PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: input is out of range (ActiveRecord::RangeError) indicates that you are trying to insert or update a numeric value in a PostgreSQL database that exceeds the allowed range for the column's data type.
We can follow below steps to resolve it:

Identify the column causing the issue.
Check the column's data type and constraints.
Ensure input values are within the allowed range.
Alter the data type if necessary via a migration.
Add validations to prevent future issues.

